# I can't remember my iCloud username or password

Tags: icloud, iphone

I can't turn on my iPhone because I don't remember my iCloud username or password.  What can I do to log into my iPhone?

Comment: Go to: [https://iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

Call Apple for help, but if you don't have any information about you AppleID, owner name, creation date, devices using, security questions, etc., then you are out of luck.

Comment: i remmber my apple ID, can i have a reset?

Comment: that's obviously not enough, the ID is visible to everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

You can have your password reset by following the steps at the Apple Recovery site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487

**Answer your security questions**
If you know the answers to your security questions, select "Answer security questions" and follow the steps to reset your password.

**Use email authentication**
If you select "Get an email," we'll send an email to your primary or rescue email address that you can use to reset your password.